# Запрет на добавление одинаковых тасков в очередь задач ExecutorService'а

Tags: блок, многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте.
Сразу хочу сказать что мой вопрос слегка бредовый. Но вот просто стало интресно, может кто-то сталкивался с такой необходимостью. Существует ли какой-то готовый способ избежать добавления в очередь задач для пула уже имеющегося там таска ? То есть чтобы очередь задач имела некую функциональность Set'а. Допустим в пул сабмитятся Runnabl'ы в которых есть поле id, и нужно обеспечить такой функционал чтобы в очередь не добавлялся Runnable с таким же id который в очеерди уже есть.
Возможно нужно отнаследоваться от BlockingQueue и переопределить тот метод очереди который вызывается пулом для добавления таска, как считаете ? 
Спасибо

Comment: хм, очередь задач же есть, вот у нее и отслеживай их уникальность...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагаю, что уникальными задачи должны быть все время работы - т.е. если задача была засабмичена и выполнена (удалена из очереди), то все равно больше засабмитить ее нельзя. 
Я вижу тут 3 варианта.

1. Реализовать `BlockingQueue` как очередь, хранящую только уникальные элементы.
2. Расширить `ThreadPoolExecutor` с переопределением метода `beforeExecute`.
3. Реализовать `ExecutorService` как пул, делегирующий свои действия "настоящему" пулу.

Расширение `BlockingQueue` будет подразумевать, что вы отклоняете таску, если такая уже есть, возвращая в соответствующем методе `false`, или "как бы" принимаете ее, возвращая `true`, но на самом деле очередь не меняете - но я не уверен, что пул это воспримет нормально. В доках предполагается, что если очередь не принимает задачу, то очередь "полна" - и предпринимает другие действия. С другой стороны, если задача принята, пул совершает дополнительные проверки. Другими словами, пул не догадается, что вы проворачиваете что-то там в очереди неожиданное, и результаты могут быть непредсказуемыми.

Во 2-м варианте вам нужно будет кидать `RuntimeException` в случае неподходящей задачи - это, во-первых, может быть очень неэффективно, если у вас много одинаковых сабмитов, а второе (вообще-то, это даже главное) - `beforeExecute` вызывается уже на этапе выполнения задачи - т.е. очередь может быть заполнена одинаковыми тасками и вы получите исключение о повторе задачи когда-то потом.

Лично я склоняюсь к последенему варианту: на мой взгляд, реализация получится более чистой и ясной для стороннего наблюдателя, и легко расширяемой в случае необходимости дополнительных проверок.

Примерно так:

```
public class DelegatingExecutorService implements ExecutorService {
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private Set<Runnable> submittedTasks;

    public DelegatingExecutorService(ExecutorService delegate) {
        executorService = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
        if (!submittedTasks.contains(task)) {
            submittedTasks.add(task);
            return executorService.submit(task);
        }
        return null; // или что-то более вам подходящее, или исключение бросайте
    }

    // реализация обычных делегирующих методов
    @Override
    public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return executorService.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Для меня нужно чтобы задачи были уникальными не все время работы а только в очереди. Для такого , по всей видимости, нужно переопределять только очередь

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в этот Runnable, в котором уже есть id,добавил поле boolean running. При постановке в очередь:
 if(!running) {executorService.execute(this); running=true;}
при окончании работы (в методе run()):
 running=false;
Ну и все это конечно с синхронизацией.